# IP Address Tracker

Tags: android, ip-address

Below is my situation.
I have machines with each assigned with a fixed IP address and router and able to transmit the signal through local mobile network. These machines will be constantly switch on and off the signal base on individual activities. I have to manually track the online status of these machines through a third party supplier. Is there anyway for me to come out with some simple apps that can receive notification or display the online status of each ip address?

Appreciate for any constructive suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just get them to send a little message to your server every few seconds or minutes. Just a simple http task. I use google spreadaheet for this task and is fairly simple and quick.

Comment: I did some google search and got something called smtp relay. is it the same thing as you mentioned?

Comment: That is a protocol for sending emails and totally different.